# JSoup not translating ampersand in links in html

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

In JSoup the following test case should pass, it is not.

```
@Test
public void shouldPrintHrefCorrectly(){
    String content=  "<li><a href=\"#\">Good</a><ul><li><a href=\"article.php?boid=1865&sid=53&mid=1\">" +
            "Boss</a></li><li><a href=\"article.php?boid=186&sid=53&mid=1\">" +
            "heavent</a></li><li><a href=\"article.php?boid=167&sid=53&mid=1\">" +
            "hellos</a></li><li><a href=\"article.php?boid=181&sid=53&mid=1\">" +
            "Mr.Jackson!</a></li>";

    Document document = Jsoup.parse(content, "http://www.google.co.in/");
    Elements links = document.select("a[href^=article]");
    Iterator<Element> iterator = links.iterator();
    List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        urls.add(iterator.next().attr("href"));
    }

    Assert.assertTrue(urls.contains("article.php?boid=181&sid=53&mid=1"));
}
```

Could any of you please give me the reason as to why it is failing?

Answer (score 1):

There are three problems:

1. You're asserting that there's a `bovikatanid` parameter is present, while it's actually called `boid`.
2. The HTML source is using `&` instead of `&amp;` in the source. This is technically invalid.
3. Jsoup is parsing `&mid` as `|` somehow. It should have scanned until `;`.

To fix #1, you have to do it yourself. To fix #2, you have to report this issue to the serveradmin in question (it's their fault, however, since the average browser is forgiving on this, I'd imagine that Google is doing this to save bandwidth). To fix #3, I've reported [an issue](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues#issue/71) to the Jsoup guy to see what he thinks about this.

---

**Update**: see, Jonathan (the Jsoup guy) has fixed it. It'll be there in the next release.

Comment: Excellent review of the code. Thanks for raising issue with JSoup. Would love to work with person like you.

Comment: Thanks BalusC. I've fixed the Jsoup unescape issue, and it'll be available in the next release.